# How to merge two tables with same schema in Talend avoiding duplicates?

Tags: etl, talend, talend-mdm

I have two tables TableA and TableB

TableA looks similar to following:

```
customerId  |  name  | email            |telephone
 -------------------------------------------------
 00001      | Anne   | anne@gmail.com   | 123456
 00002      | Ben    | ben@gmail.com    | 
 00003      | Ryan   | ryan@yahoo.com   |
```

TableB looks similar to following:

```
customerId | name   | email            | telephone
 ---------------------------------------------------
 76105      | Anne   | anne@gmail.com   | 
 89102      | Ben    | ben@gmail.com    | 567890
 23390      | Ryan   | ryan@yahoo.com   | 756541
 43769      | Abby   | abby@yahoo.com   | 890437
```

I'm trying to achieve the following 2 tables.

TableC

```
 customerId  |  name  | email            |telephone
 -------------------------------------------------
  00001      | Anne   | anne@gmail.com   | 123456
  00002      | Ben    | ben@gmail.com    | 567890
  00003      | Ryan   | ryan@yahoo.com   | 756541
```

TableD

```
 customerId  |  name  | email            |telephone
 -------------------------------------------------
  43769      | Abby   | abby@gmail.com   | 890437
```

I was using a tmap with TableA as the main and the TableB as the look up. In the tmap I created an inner join between TableA and TableB using `email` as the foreign key. I wrote innerJoin outputs to one table and innerJoin rejects to another. However I find some of the records missing in TableC.

What is the correct way to achieve this in Talend DI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the choice of the main and the lookup impact the reject catching, here is what you need :

[image]

- tmap :

[image]

- tFixedFlowInput : to simulate your data
- tLogRow: to display output data

Comment: Thank you. This is very clear. I had to reverse my look up and main as you have pointed out.